# Save binarydata into a image file in c# / silverlight 3

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, save, binary-data

```
   byte[] binaryData = new Byte[pngStream.Length];
   long bytesRead = pngStream.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)pngStream.Length);

   string base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData,
                                                          0,
                                                          binaryData.Length);
```

I have a binary data in Byte array. 
Does anybody know how to save this into any image file (png or jpg) in silverlight3 or c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To save a byte array (verbatim) to a file :

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\YourFile.png", binaryData);
```

Is that what you are after ?

Answer (score 0):

What format is your pixel data is in?

In any case, take a look at the ImageTools library: http://imagetools.codeplex.com/

Save yourself from reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like the data is already in the format you want, the question seems more like "how to I save the contents of a stream to a file", which Moe answered correctly.  If storing it all in memory were a concern, you could [File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) and then copy from one stream to another (if in .Net 4, you can use the [new CopyTo method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) to do it for you - if downlevel you can do it manually or just use an extension method to get the same behavior :)

If you happen to need to change the format of the image, you can use System.Drawing.Image for that.  For instance, [Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) and then [the Save method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx).